# What is the best way to locally store XML in an HTML5-based PhoneGap Android app?

Tags: android, xml, html, cordova

which is the secure and fastest method of storing and retriving data (xml file / xml content) in phoneGap Android application?

```
window.localStorage.setItem('xml','datastring'); / getItem();
```

or

```
using SQL DB
```

or

```
using FileTransfer
```

Currently I am using FileTransfer. My database get hits - consider more then 100 times per minute. Which will be most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient ways would be to do it by `localStorage or SQLiteDB`. For more efficiency, I would suggest reading the data and storing in `sessionStorage` and saving while exiting the application.

Now, both the options are not so secure compared to Network, but works well if the data is not sensitive and also you are not concerned of user wiping out the app data.